# Converting yyyymmdd to MM-dd-yyyy format in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large data frame df containing a column for date in the format `yyyymmdd`, how can I convert it into `MM-dd-yyyy` in pySpark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType


rdd = sc.parallelize(['20161231', '20140102', '20151201', '20161124'])
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ['old_col'])

# UDF to convert string to date
func =  udf (lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d'), DateType())

df = df1.withColumn('new_col', date_format(func(col('old_col')), 'MM-dd-yyy'))

df.show()
```

Comment: Thanks mrsrinivas, I am using Zeppelin and this code is ran without error but I am not able to work(actions or transformations) on the result of your code. I am very new to Spark, please help me if I am missing something.

Comment: use `df.show()` for final output. you might have loaded data to dataframe(`df1`)

Comment: Thanks mrsinivas, a little change was all I was missing, I will post my change also if someone else find it useful. Thanks again.

Comment: Minor snippet correction: It misses ```from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format```

Answer (score 0):

This is also working:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,udf,unix_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType


func =  udf(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), '%m%d%y'), DateType())

df2 = df.withColumn('date', func(col('InvcDate')))
```

Comment: Do you get output in this format `MM-dd-yyyy`. I think it give it in `yyyy-MM-dd`.