# Convert OffsetDateTimeUdt to date or string

Tags: python, sql, datetime, pyspark, datetimeoffset

I am working on Pyspark.
I have a column `end_date`, I want to make some work on it. But I can't due to his type: `OffsetDateTimeUdt`.

It's possible to convert this type in date or string ?

Exemple of value:`2021-08-15T00:00:00.000Z`

If you have any idea please let me know :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you the code you have tried?

Comment: bio_t=bio_w.selectExpr('customer','TO_DATE(end_date)  as date','operator')  I also tried CAST

Comment: what is says ? `bio_t= bio_w.selectExpr('customer','CAST(TO_DATE(end_date) AS DATE) dt','operator')`. can you add error message

Comment: of course: u"cannot resolve 'CAST(ri.foundry.main.dataset.bb7b7376-3e35-46c4-beb1-0cb2b3651c89.`end_date` AS DATE)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast com.palantir.spark.time.OffsetDateTimeUdt@0 to DateType 
   the error message is very long but I think the most important is here

Comment: I would recommend you to write a UDF to convert `OffsetDateTimeUdt` to `String/DateTime`

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I am not very familiar with UDF do you have a link or an example to advise me ?

Comment: you can [create udf like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41392738/1592191)

Answer (score 0):

Convert into timestamp by ignoring the milliseconds like below

```
x = spark.createDataFrame([("2021-08-15T00:00:00.000Z",)], ['date_str'])
x.select(x.date_str, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(x.date_str,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000Z'"))).show(truncate=False)
```

output:

```
+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|date_str                |from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_str, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000Z'), yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)|
+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2021-08-15T00:00:00.000Z|2021-08-15 00:00:00                                                                       |
+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```